# drop/reset one/multiple (specified) models from database with django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I've added a field to my django model. Now, since I've had some instances of this model already, they not include this field resulting in django error page. I'm not able to manually delete those instances from admin panel.

I've searched that `python manage.py flush` is a way to go for reseting whole db, but I would like to delete only this particular model.

Is there a way to do this from the CLI ?

> Solution:
> For starting question, I accept @IainShelvington answer:

```
python manage.py shell
# then
from app_name.models import model_name
model_name.objects.all().delete()
```

> Additionally, thanks to @AbdulAzizBarkat for providing:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero
```

Comment: Just to be sure. After adding new fields you have run python manage makemigrations and python manage migrate commands?

Comment: You want to delete all data for a model? Run `Model.objects.all().delete()` in a shell

Comment: @VJMagar You have a point. I wasn't able to do this, because django wants me to specify a default value for already existing instances (this is how I interpreted this), but this new field is `ForeignKey`, thus I don't want to specify default

Comment: @IainShelvington How can I use this is CMD ?

Comment: Use `python manage.py shell` to open a Django shell then import your model and run the delete

Comment: @IainShelvington with Yours solution I get columns relation error between models. Possibly because of `ForeignKey`. Is there a way to force it ?

Comment: The `ForeignKey` was not created with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`?

Comment: @Wiktoor just migrate with a default first and then delete. As it is your models and database don't match and you are trying to execute some query (most likely this is why you get the error).

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, exactly. It is strange, because the field is `hired_user = models.ForeignKey(HiredUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and it gives me error with default value. I've deleted whole db with `python manage.py flush` and all migrations. Now `makemigraions` gives me the same issuse with default value.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've deleted whole db, but running `makemigrations` (after deleting previous) gives me same `default value` error.

Comment: @Wiktoor the default value is not an error. It is just Django being logical. You say _"but running makemigrations (after deleting previous)"_ does this mean you only deleted that one previous migration? Since you have flushed your database you might as well delete all of your previous migrations and the pyc files (except the `__init__` file) and migrate again. Now you should not have any issues since this would be your first migration.

Comment: @Wiktoor Note: the flush command: _Removes all data from the database and re-executes any post-synchronization handlers. The table of which migrations have been applied is not cleared._ You might as well have migrated to zero instead. `python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, I've deleted all migration including `initial`. Deleted whole db, done `makemigrations` as first, then `migrate`. Now migrations seems to work, but `no default value` issue still presist.